# Nativescript can't find six

Tags: python, nativescript, six

I installed Nativescript successfully and it works when running `ns run android`.

However, when I try to use `ns run ios` I get the ominous `WARNING: The Python 'six' package not found.`-error

Same happens, when I try to use `ns doctor`.

I tried EVERYTHING that I found on the web. Setting PATH, PYTHONPATH, re-install python, six and everything - nothing helped.

Re-install of six tells me `Requirement already satisfied`.

Any ideas how to make this work???

I'm on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have a total mess with paths and python installations on my Mac.

I found like 6 different pip-paths and like 4 different python paths.

Since I have no idea which ones I can delete, I tried installing six with all pip-versions I found and that helped.

How to clean up this mess is likely a subject for another thread :)